# Integration with third-parties?

Tags: commerce, rules, services

I'm trying to integrate Drupal Commerce to a File Maker. Why ? Because my client staffing have been using File Maker for over 15+ years. We are trying to integrate both systems.

So my goal is to be able to send the order information every time a purchase is complete to the File Maker server so they can re-created their order information into File Maker as well.

I started to write [my custom module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/darol100/2335737) to send the order ID to the File Maker server. Here is how I did it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_checkout_complete().
 */
function commerce_external_call_order_commerce_checkout_complete($order){
  $script_variable = variable_get ('external_script');
  // Combine the URL with the OrderID.
  $final_variable = file_get_contents($script_variable . $order->order_id);

}
```

And this actually works.

I'm wondering if there is a module that allows me to export my order information every time an order is complete or updated? Ideally would be an integration with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and the [Service](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/services_rules . It creates actions (usable in rules) for the services module. It's in beta because it has a limited amount of features. It is stable though.